# Error 500 when i use htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made `.htaccsess` for include path and i set in it

```
php_value include_path ".;c:\xampp\php\PEAR;c:\xampp\htdocs\shop\shop\inc";
```

there is just top line(htaccess)

my project is in locall 
and my include file is in directory: `c:\xampp\htdocs\shop\shop\inc`

but when i use function or classess in my include directory i get This Error:

> Server error!
>   The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 500
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9

in error.log apache is

```
[Sun Oct 19 17:07:08.037451 2014] [core:alert] [pid 2228:tid 1676] [client ::1:52965] C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/shop/.htaccess: php_value takes two arguments, PHP Value Modifier
```

[Sun Oct 19 17:07:09.559628 2014] [core:alert] [pid 2228:tid 1676] [client ::1:52966] C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/shop/.htaccess: php_value takes two arguments, PHP Value Modifier

Comment: To debug this error, you have to check your apache error log

Comment: What are you trying to do? From that code you provided it seems you are trying to include PHP files using a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: in log appach :[Sun Oct 19 17:07:08.037451 2014] [core:alert] [pid 2228:tid 1676] [client ::1:52965] C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/shop/.htaccess: php_value takes two arguments, PHP Value Modifier

Answer (score 0):

```
php_value include_path ".;c:/xampp/php/PEAR;c:/xampp/htdocs/shop/shop/inc"
```

Try it with forward slashes and without the semicolon at the end.

Also retype the spaces to make sure you've not introduced some non ascii character into the string.